# How to Find The intersection and Union of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: probability

In a certain population of people, $15\%$ will contract Disease $A$ at some point in their lifetime, $19\%$ will contract Disease $B$ at some point in their lifetime, and $65\%$ will not contract either of these diseases in their lifetime.

A person from this population is randomly chosen.

Find the probability that the person chosen contracts Disease $A$ or Disease $B$.

What I've done so far:
Figure out the probability that they contract disease $A$ and disease $B$, $P(A \cap B)$.

I think these events are independent. Therefore $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

therefore the $P(A \cap B) = 0.0285$.

The probability of $A$ or $B$ can be written like this: $P(A)+P(B) + P(A \cap B)= 0.3685$.

But these are not correct (neither my intersection probability or union probability)

Comment: Why do you think that $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$P(A^c \cap B^c)=P((A \cup B)^c)=1-P(A \cup B)$$

Are you able to answer the question now?

By the way, you might like to check the numbers given in the question if they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

What reason do you have to assume that contracting disease A and disease B are independent?  In fact, if they were **mutually exclusive**, and, of course, not getting either diseases is mutually exclusive of getting either A or B, we should have the probabilities adding to 1.  But .15+ .19+ .65= .99.  If they are not mutually exclusive, the sum would be smaller.  The numbers you give, whether "independent", "dependent", or "mutually exclusive", [b]cannot[/b] be correct.